# QTP Cannot Create ActiveX Object

Tags: vbscript, activex, qtp

While working on script, I am facing this  issue.

I can't post the whole code but this is a sample that does the samething that I wrote myself;

```
Dim qtpApp
Set qtpApp = createObject("QuickTest.Application")
qtpApp.Launch
```

I have also tried this:

```
Set qtpApp = createObject("QuickTest.application")
```

And This:

```
Set qtpApp = createObject("Quick Test.Application")
```

But I Keep Getting "Active X Component cant create object. on Line x: "Set qtpApp = createObject("QuickTest.Application")"

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct prog-id is the one you tried first `"QuickTest.Application"`.

The probable cause for this is that QTP isn't installed correctly on your machine.
To verify if this is the case

1. Try launching QTP manually
2. Check that the following key exists in the registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTest.Application\CLSID`
3. Take the classid from the registry and check that the key for it exists under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID` (or if it's a 64 bit machine `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID`)
4. Verify that under this key the `LocalServer32` points to "QtpAutomationAgent.exe" under QTP's bin directory

Comment: everything checks out fine.however I still get the error. I think I may have found the problem however, I have IBM sametime and I belive the java addins and the sametime add ins are conflicting. How I remove the jave addins?

Comment: Did anyone get any solution to this problem. I also verified the above, it is fine. But still I get the same error. Uninstalling/Installing QTP did not work either.