# QTP: ActiveX can not create Object

Tags: activex, qtp, hp-quality-center

[image: Run Error]

I tried to connect to SA Api from Quick Test Professional. 
But it ran into an error and displays "ActiveX-Component cannot create an Object: "SAClient80MP.SAapi".

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `CreateObject` from QTP you get VBScript's native [CreateObject](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_createobject.asp), this means that your question is VBScript/COM and doesn't really have to do with QTP. 
To verify that I'm correct you can place the `CreateObject` line in a `.vbs` file and try to run it.

The way COM works is that it looks for a key with the same name as the [progid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProgID) in the registry (under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`) so in this example you should look for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SAClient80MP.SAapi`.

For information on how to trouble shoot this see my answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11288776/3848).